# How to delete a row depending of the value of another column with indexed data

Tags: python, pandas

Really I need to solve a data cleaning, my target is keep the older date according with variable 'codCie'

I have indexed my dataset with the columns as appear with the command:

`df_temp2.set_index(['idClie','sexo', 'edad'], inplace = True)`

`df_temp2.head()`

OUTPUT:

```
idClie  sexo    edad    codCie  fechaConsulta
100020  F   64.0    I10X    2010-07-03
        64.0    I10X    2012-03-23
        64.0    R060    2016-11-24
        64.0    R060    2016-11-25
        64.0    R060    2016-11-26
        64.0    R060    2016-11-27
        64.0    R060    2016-11-28
100073  M   69.0    I471    2006-07-31
        69.0    I471    2007-02-21
        69.0    I471    2007-04-03
        69.0    I471    2007-04-04
        69.0    I471    2007-05-02
        69.0    I471    2008-01-02
        69.0    I471    2008-11-05
        69.0    I471    2009-02-18
        69.0    I499    2009-06-26
        69.0    R000    2020-02-07
        69.0    R074    2005-04-18
```

However I need to remove for each 'idCliente' where in variable 'codCie' is appearing different value, remove the new one on the column 'fechaConsulta'. My target is that output should be as follow:

```
idClie  sexo    edad    codCie  fechaConsulta
100020  F   64.0    I10X    2010-07-03
        64.0    R060    2016-11-24
100073  M   69.0    I471    2006-07-31
        69.0    I499    2009-06-26
        69.0    R000    2020-02-07
        69.0    R074    2005-04-18
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a new dataframe, loop through the index and [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) in the "codCie" column (keeping the first).  I have looped through unique index values so that I could group together the data to drop the duplicates.

```
import pandas as pd

df_temp2 = pd.read_csv("data_csv.csv")

df_temp2.set_index(['idClie','sexo', 'edad'], inplace = True)

new_data = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df_temp2.index.unique():
    new_data = new_data.append(df_temp2.loc[i].drop_duplicates(subset=["codCie"], keep="first"))
```

Using the output data you provided, creating a .csv file with it (in the future it would be helpful to provide this, or the dataframe code you used to create the dataframe to make it easier to answer your question), I returned this as the output:

```
print(new_data)

#                 codCie fechaConsulta
#idClie sexo edad                     
#100020 F    64     I10X    03/07/2010
#            64     R060    24/11/2016
#100073 M    69     I471    31/07/2006
#            69     I499    26/06/2009
#            69     R000    07/02/2020
#            69     R074    18/04/2005
```